# dup2 to redirect stdout and stderr to another file descriptor

Tags: c++, stdout, stderr, dup2

i have  a call like this.

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd)
```

and then

```
dup2(fd[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO)
```

is there a way to use the dup call to duplicate both 1 and 2 to fd[WRITE]?

Comment: I am not sure I know what fd[WRITE] is in this situation.  Can you provide a larger example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just repeat this operation for stderr.

```
dup2(fd[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd[WRITE], STDERR_FILENO);
```